# Two queries in one SQL event

Tags: mysql

hi i have this sql event

[image]

now i want to add this query to this event

`INSERT INTO leave_records (ID_NUM, TYPE, ADDITIONAL, DATE) SELECT tbl_leave.ID_NUM, 'VL/SL', '1.25', CURDATE() FROM tbl_leave WHERE tbl_leave.STATUS = 'On'`

both of the queries run perfectly..

but the problem is i have this error,

[image]

when i am putting the two queries together in this one event. i tried to run one query at a time from this event and everything works fine. but i need this two queries run at the same time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try splitting your queries with semicolon
EDIT: Try adding BEGIN and END like:

```
BEGIN
 query1; 
 query2; 
END
```

Comment: i already tried it. then just now i tried it again and still have the same error.

Comment: Try adding BEGIN and END like:
 BEGIN
query1;
query2;
END